# Framesubtitle is missing

Tags: beamer, frame-title

My Code:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % default family is serif
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{black}\insertframetitle}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\normalfont\tiny}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{5}{2}\selectfont}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\begin{document}
\title{Titel der Vorlesung} 
\subtitle{SoSe XXXX} 
\author{Max Mustermann}
\date{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Deskriptive Beschreibung linearer Zusammenhänge}
\framesubtitle{Untertitel in kleiner Schrift}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Problems:

- the framesubtitle is not displayed
- how can i change the distance of the frametitle to the top of the slide?

[image]

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{black}\insertframetitle}` inserts only the title.

Comment: If i use \setbeamertemplate{framesubtitle}{\color{black}\insertframesubtitle}
 nothing happens

Comment: @Eric There is no template called `framesubtitle`, you need to use `\insertframesubtitle` in the frametitle template.

Comment: @Eric You should accept the answer composed by samcarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{black}\insertframetitle}` you overwrite the default layout to only display the frametitle, no spacing around and no subtitle.

Instead I would simply use the frametitle template provided by your theme and adjust the colours to fit your needs. This has the advantage that not only the subtitle will be displayed automatically, but also that colours, fonts etc. can be controlled via the usual colour and font templates.

The spacing above can simply be adjusted by not setting the headline to empty, but to whatever vertical space you like, e.g. `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace*{0.3cm}}`.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useoutertheme{shadow}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % default family is serif
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\normalfont\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{5}{2}\selectfont}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=white, bg=structure.fg}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace*{0.3cm}}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(bg);
    color(4pt)=(bg)}
}
\makeatother

\title{Titel der Vorlesung} 
\subtitle{SoSe XXXX} 
\author{Max Mustermann}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Deskriptive Beschreibung linearer Zusammenhänge}
\framesubtitle{Untertitel in kleiner Schrift}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Off-topic:

- there is a superfluous `\makeatother` in your code
- instead of `\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}` I suggest `\useoutertheme{shadow}`

Comment: That works. But another Problem: The framesubtitle is not exactly left-adjusted with the frametitle.

Comment: And beetween the both title there shoud be a little more space

Comment: @Eric It is in my example. If this is not the case for you, please show a MWE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Eric To add more space, you'll need to redefine the frametitle template. You can find the original in `shadowoutertheme.sty`. However comments are not the space to ask new questions.

Comment: Back to the left-adjusted - when you look at the output of your code, the frametitle is a little bit closer to the left margin - you see it clesrer when you write an U as first letter in frametitle too

Comment: The title and subtitle are aligned, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw7Gn.png. The difference you see comes from the font of different sizes. Same happens if you write `U\\ \tiny U` in normal text.

Comment: I have solved the problem using a \hspace